# Java.lang.NoClasssDefFoundError: I am getting this exception when I am calling hibernate session through Message Driven Bean class

Tags: hibernate, ejb

BEA-010065> <MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception was:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.integration.web.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.integration.web.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory

```
    at com.integration.web.PublishAction.sendResponse(EssAction.java:44)
```

Comment: Please help me how to get hibernate session in Message Driven Bean class. I am using myeclipse.

Comment: The exception `NoClassDefFoundError` means the class is not found in classpath at runtime. Where does the `com.integration.web.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory` come from? Can the jar containing this class be found in your classpath?

Comment: Lini, I am using hibernate3.jar. I have set this jar under configuration build path in myeclipse. I got hibernate session through Java class. But I am getting this exception only when I calling hibernate session through Message Driven Bean class.

Comment: The class `com.integration.web.*` is not from hibernate3.jar. You can open the jar file and see. Also check that the referenced jar fies are either included in target executable or in classpath at runtime.